# PHP with Serverless (on AWS Lambda): PDO connection problem

Tags: php, pdo, lambda, serverless

I am trying to run a PHP function on Lambda using Serverless Framework (http://blog.zerosharp.com/the-serverless-framework-and-php/).
Everything works, except when I try to initialise a PDO MySql connection. If I do so, testing locally it works, while testing remotely it fails immediately.

This is my code  (very very straightforward):

```
<?php
$result = updateArxivar();

printf(json_encode($result));

function updateArxivar(){
    $db_host = "my_host";
    $db_name = "my_dbname";
    $db_username = getenv("FLY_DATABASE_USER");
    $db_password = getenv("FLY_DATABASE_PW");
    try{ 
        $conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_host.';dbname='.$db_name, 
$db_username, $db_password);
    }catch(Exception $e){
        fwrite(STDERR, "Hi\n");
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Seems like the Lambda env is not configured to support PDO. So, I edited the dockerfile like this: https://gist.github.com/Delfins/23aadc9e418c48e88c4a7491641dc0c9 but still no differences.
This is the error I'm getting:

serveless_pn@ip-10-0-1-146:~/site/serverless-php$ sls invoke --function hello
{
    "errorMessage": "Process exited with non-zero status code 255",
    "errorType": "Error",
    "stackTrace": [
        "ChildProcess. (/var/task/handler.js:30:23)",
        "emitTwo (events.js:106:13)",
        "ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)",
        "maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:886:16)",
        "Socket. (internal/child_process.js:342:11)",
        "emitOne (events.js:96:13)",
        "Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)",
        "Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:497:12)"
    ]
}

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: are you using aws rds as your mysql server ?

Comment: @sking I'm trying both situations: I tried to connect to a pure MySQL public DB and to my private RDS MySQL instance....in both situations, error.

Comment: does your lamda has internet access ? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc.html#vpc-internet this may help you to configure it

Comment: you can try to connect mysql using node.js first ?  https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql.asp If it doesn't work. It must be internet access issue I believe.